# Remove Last Non-NA Value from Dataframe

Tags: r, replace, na

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4   Col5     Col6     Col7
  10       A       B        C     NA       NA       NA
  12       B       P        V      G       NA       NA
  14       C       I        K      H        M        H
  55       N       K       NA     NA       NA       NA
  34       M       N        O      P        Q       NA
```

How do I remove the last non-NA value in each row and replace with NA?

Final output:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4   Col5     Col6     Col7
  10       A       B       NA     NA       NA       NA
  12       B       P        V     NA       NA       NA
  14       C       I        K      H        M       NA
  55       N      NA       NA     NA       NA       NA
  34       M       N        O      P       NA       NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to find the last non-NA element per row, then with row/column indexing, set those elements to NA in the original dataset

```
df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), max.col(!is.na(df1), 'last'))] <- NA
df1
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7
#1   10    A    B <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#2   12    B    P    V <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3   14    C    I    K    H    M <NA>
#4   55    N <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#5   34    M    N    O    P <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. Btw this is all stemming from this question that I cannot figure out so I am trying to break it off piece by piece. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006044/match-dataframes-excluding-last-non-na-value-and-disregarding-order