# Seeing if all values in one dataframe row exist in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, match

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df1    

ColA     ColB     ColC     ColD
  10        A        B        L
  11        N        Q       NA
  12        P        J        L
  43        M        T       NA
  89        O        J        T

df2

ATTR      Att      R1   R2    R3    R4
   1       45       A    B    NA    NA
   2       40       C    D    NA    NA
   3       33       T    J     O    NA
   4       65       L   NA    NA    NA
   5       20       P    L     J    NA
   6       23       Q   NA    NA    NA
   7       38       Q    L    NA    NA
```

How do I match up df2 with df1 so that if ALL the values in each df2 row (disregarding the order) show up in the df1 rows, then it will populate. So it is checking if ALL not just one value from each df2 row matches up with each df1 row. The final result in this case should be this:

```
ColA     ColB     ColC     ColD   ATTR      Att      R1   R2    R3    R4
  10        A        B        L      1       45       A    B    NA    NA
  10        A        B        L      4       65       L   NA    NA    NA
  11        N        Q       NA      6       23       Q   NA    NA    NA
  12        P        J        L      4       65       L   NA    NA    NA
  12        P        J        L      5       20       P    L     J    NA    
  89        O        J        T      3       33       T    J     O    NA
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using base R.

Make sure everything is a character before continuing, i.e.

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.character)
df1[-c(1:2)] <- lapply(df1[-c(1:2)], as.character)
```

First we create two lists which contain vectors of the rowwise elements of each data frame. We then create a matrix with the length of elements from `l2` are found in `l1`, If the length is 0 then it means they match. i.e,

```
l1 <- lapply(split(df[-1], seq(nrow(df))), function(i) i[!is.na(i)])
l2 <- lapply(split(df1[-c(1:2)], seq(nrow(df1))), function(i) i[!is.na(i)])

m1 <- sapply(l1, function(i) sapply(l2, function(j) length(setdiff(j, i))))
m1
#  1 2 3 4 5
#1 0 2 2 2 2
#2 2 2 2 2 2
#3 3 3 2 2 0
#4 0 1 0 1 1
#5 2 3 0 3 2
#6 1 0 1 1 1
#7 1 1 1 2 2
```

We then use that matrix to create a couple of coloumns in our original `df`. The first column `rpt` will indicate how many times each row has length 0 and use that as a number of repeats for each row. We also use it to filter out all the 0 lengths (i.e. the rows that do not have a match with `df1`). After expanding the data frame we create another variable; `ATTR` (same name as `ATTR` in `df1`) in order to use it for a `merge`. i.e.

```
df$rpt <- colSums(m1 == 0)
df <- df[df$rpt != 0,]
df <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$rpt),]
df$ATTR <- which(m1 == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]
df
#    ColA ColB ColC ColD rpt ATTR
#1     10    A    B    L   2    1
#1.1   10    A    B    L   2    4
#2     11    N    Q <NA>   1    6
#3     12    P    J    L   2    4
#3.1   12    P    J    L   2    5
#5     89    O    J    T   1    3
```

We then `merge` and order the two data frames,

```
final_df <- merge(df, df1, by = 'ATTR')

final_df[order(final_df$ColA),]
#  ATTR ColA ColB ColC ColD rpt Att R1   R2   R3   R4
#1    1   10    A    B    L   2  45  A    B <NA> <NA>
#3    4   10    A    B    L   2  65  L <NA> <NA> <NA>
#6    6   11    N    Q <NA>   1  23  Q <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4    4   12    P    J    L   2  65  L <NA> <NA> <NA>
#5    5   12    P    J    L   2  20  P    L    J <NA>
#2    3   89    O    J    T   1  33  T    J    O <NA>
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ColA = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 43L, 89L), ColB = c("A", 
"N", "P", "M", "O"), ColC = c("B", "Q", "J", "T", "J"), ColD = c("L", 
NA, "L", NA, "T")), .Names = c("ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dput(df1)
structure(list(ATTR = 1:7, Att = c(45L, 40L, 33L, 65L, 20L, 23L, 
38L), R1 = c("A", "C", "T", "L", "P", "Q", "Q"), R2 = c("B", 
"D", "J", NA, "L", NA, "L"), R3 = c(NA, NA, "O", NA, "J", NA, 
NA), R4 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), .Names = c("ATTR", 
"Att", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That looks like it works! Can't thank you enough. A very intuitive way of doing this. Thanks @Sotos